# Make key for dict from list-object

Tags: python, dictionary

I have list:

```
k = ["key1", "subkey2", "subsubkey3"]
```

I know for certain that `d` is a dict such that `d["key1"]["subkey2"]["subsubkey3"]` is valid.

How can I transform list `k` as a key for dict `d` so as to return `d[k[0]][k[1]]...`?

Comment: you mean that `d[k[0]]` is a dictionary containing key `k[1]` that contains a dictionary with key `k[2]`?

Comment: besides: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, that was I mean.

Comment: @SkyFox Your question is a good one, rephrase it and use codify some parts to make it more readable.

Comment: `d[k[0]][k[1]][k[2]]`

Answer (score 9):

You can try using [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) with [`operator.getitem`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.getitem):

```
>>> from operator import getitem
>>> 
>>> d = {'key1': {'subkey2': {'subsubkey3': 'value'}}}
>>> k = ["key1", "subkey2", "subsubkey3"]
>>> 
>>> reduce(getitem, k, d)
'value'
```

In Python 3.x, you should use [`functools.reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

---

`reduce()` simply takes a 2-argument function and applies it to the elements of a list consecutively, accumulating the result. There is also an optional *initializer* argument, which we have used here. As the docs state, `reduce()` is roughly equivalent to:

```
def reduce(function, iterable, initializer=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    if initializer is None:
        try:
            initializer = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            raise TypeError('reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value')
    accum_value = initializer
    for x in it:
        accum_value = function(accum_value, x)
    return accum_value
```

In our case, we are passing an `initializer` so it will not be `None`. Hence what we have is:

```
def reduce(function, iterable, initializer=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    accum_value = initializer
    for x in it:
        accum_value = function(accum_value, x)
    return accum_value
```

Our `function` in this case is `getitem(a, b)` (see link above) which simply returns the `a[b]`. Moreover, our `iterable` is `k` and our `initializer` is `d`. So the `reduce()` call above is equivalent to:

```
accum_value = d
for x in k:
    accum_value = accum_value[x]
```

Comment: This was excellent. I learnt something new, thanks. Would you mind explaining it in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 3):

```
temp_d = d
for key in k:
 temp_d = temp_d[key]
```

After this code finishes temp_d will contain your value

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the few times when `reduce` might be a good idea - what it does is successively apply the same operation on a value.

```
items = {'foo': {'bar': {'baz': 123}}}
keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
reduce(lambda d, k: d[k], keys, items)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
items = {'foo': …}
keys = ['foo', …]

result = items
for k in keys:
    # The RHS here is the function passed to reduce(), applied to the 
    # (intermediate) result and the current step in the loop 
    result = items[k]
```